# Wordpress: Displaying only selected taxonomy tags

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

In Wordpress I created a taxonomy called "Cities" for a CPT called "People". I want to display all taxonomy tags selected for a person in the template of the single.php-file.

What is the code for displaying only those elements selected?

I use the following code in the single-people.php:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'cities';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy); 

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
  <ul>
  <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo wp_get_post_terms($term -> slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term -> name; ?></a></li>
  <?php 
  } ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want only the selected taxonomy tags without link.

Comment: beside of links, whats wrong with taxonomy names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to display all the *terms* of a *taxonomy* selected for a single *post*.

You need to use the function [**wp_get_post_terms()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) like this:

```
$taxonomy = 'cities';
$post_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( "fields" => "names" ) );

foreach ( $post_terms as $term ) {
    echo $term; 
}
```

This will print all the names of the *cities* the current *post* is related to. Now you have to adapt this code to your page and, if you don't want links, just do not use `<a>` tags...

Answer (score -1):

```html
$wrap = 'hello';
$terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID( ), $wrap, array("fields"=>"names"));
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  echo $term;
}
```

in the place of hello you take the taxonomy name and it surely run